# how to retrieve row value using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

source code:

```
$display = 1004;
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT id, username FROM users where parentid=$diplay");
$resrow = mysql_fetch_row($result1); 
$g = $resrow[0]; 
$g1 = $resrow[1]; 
$g2 = $resrow[3]; -error not display
$g3 = $resrow[4];
$g4 = $resrow[5];


echo "ID: $g";
echo "ID: $g2";
echo "ID: $g3";
echo "ID: $g4";
```

i have to show 1005, 1007, 1008 but i can retrieve $g value only:

ans: 1004 daniel

how i can show other values 1007,1008

Table

```
id           ----name  -----    parentid
-----------------------------------
1004            daniel         1003
1005            peter          1004
1007            michael        1004
1008            sam            1004
```

ans:

```
        $g
        1004
     /        \
    g2         g3   
   1005       1007
```

Comment: could you show the table structure

Comment: i think even i am sure that 0,1,4,4,5 are not the colon name ... you need to use the colon name in `$resrow['colon name here']`

Comment: where are these values coming from? `1005, 1007, 1008`?

Comment: id name parentid  1004 daniel 1003,   1005  peter  1004,  1007 michael 1004, 1008 sam  1004

Comment: but you have only projected two columns: `id, username`. you can't fetch for parentID in this case.

Comment: life saving ---[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: i want to fetch these values 1005, 1007, 1008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing *rows* with *columns*.  On this database:

```
users
id    | name    |  parentid
------+---------+----------
1004  | daniel  |  1003
1005  | peter   |  1004
1007  | michael |  1004
1008  | sam     |  1004
```

The query  `SELECT id, name FROM users where parentid=1004` will return rows 1005, 1007, and 1008.

`mysql_fetch_row()` only fetches one row at a time.
That's **across** (the `id` and `name`), **not down** (several `id`s).

To get a list of all of the ID values that match, you need to loop through *all* the rows:

```
$parentid = 1004;
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `parentid`=$parentid" );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $result ) ){ $IDs[] = $row[0]; }
// $IDs is now an array holding each id from the resultset.
// It will look something like:
/*
array(3) {
 [0]=>
    int(1005)
 [1]=>
    int(1007)
 [2]=>
    int(1008)
}
*/
```

As mentioned above, **don't use `ext/mysql` for new work**.  I'm using it here only because that's how you asked your original question.  You need to update your code and use `ext/mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Hi, echo "$IDs[0]";  echo "$IDs[1]"; this is correct way to print the value?. thanks

Answer (score 2):

From your mysql query, you can only get column `id` and `username`. You need to modify your sql to include more columns.

Comment: i need to show id number only, like 1005, 1007, 1008 based on parentid

Answer (score 2):

You only select id and username in your query, which might have returned array like this

```
array(
    'id'=> 1005
    'username'=> 'name'
)
```

if 1005,1007,1008 are child of 1004. you might want to do

```
while($resrow = mysql_fetch_array( $result1 )){
    echo "ID:". $resrow['id'];
    echo "Name:". $resrow['username'];
}
```

Comment: Hi, i have to show individual value like $resrow[0], $resrow[1], $resrow[2], only first 3 values only i need to show. thanks,

Comment: @user1799052 noop he is right .. you need to use the loop if you want to get the multiple row as you wanted

Comment: then why do you want to echo ID? to show only the ID, just run the loop and echo only `$resrow['id']`.

Comment: just echo a separator to see if it is correct. `echo $resrow['id'].':';`. The result will be `1005,1007,1008,`.